# Formatting profile forms

Tags: profile, forms

I'm looking for advice on formatting how my profile and event registration forms are displayed. In particular the positions of labels, pre/post form help etc. Is there a general guide to changing how these are displayed?

Cheers.

Comment: Sort of, but it can sometimes be hard to maintain when you upgrade. One way is the example here: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_alterContent/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These can be controlled by CSS.  CSS is a generic skill for positioning elements on web pages, and CSS-specific questions are out of scope for this Stack Exchange, but there are many CSS tutorials on the Internet.  To add custom CSS to CiviCRM, you can upload a file and designate it via **Administer menu > System Settings > Resource URLs** and fill in the **Custom CSS URL**.  Your CMS should also have a way to include custom CSS, which is also an option.

Comment: Thanks. I've had a good play and got things almost how I want. To ask a specific question: is there a way I can target a specific label with additional CSS?

Comment: @AndrewMetheven Yes, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935064/css-target-label-based-on-for-attribute